# Рандомно прерывается воспроизведение видео в билде Unity на девайсе

Tags: unity3d

Я воспроизвожу видео на сцене с помощью компонента Video Player.
В play моде все работает отлично, однако же в билде на реальном устройстве видео рандомно может прекратить воспроизведение, а может и не прекратить.

**Устройство**: iPhone 13 mini.

**Настройки компонента Video Player**:
Source - Video Clip
Update Mode - Unscaled Game Time
Wait For First Frame - true
Skip On Drop - false

[image: Cкрин компонента Video Player]

Я пробовал запустить это же видео в новом пустом проекте, где на сцене был только Video Player. Видео отыгрывает до конца стабильно.

Я пробовал запустить это же видео в новом пустом проекте, где на сцене был только Video Player. Видео отыгрывает до конца стабильно ,но подлагивает звук из видео.

Так же пробовал делать пустую сцену в моем проблемном проекте, видео воспроизводится так же не стабильно.

Еще попробовал добавить другое видео на пустой сцене в проблемном проекте, оно воспроизводится стабильно.

Как сделать так, чтобы нужное видео воспроизводилось корректно на нужной мне сцене?
Какие настройки можно потрогать для этого?

Comment: Я заметил, что когда воспроизводится видео, нагрузка на процессор устройства растет с каждой секундой. И в момент, когда появляются фризы, нагрузка составляет 110% - 120%